# Show that the set $A:=\{f\in{C[0,1]}: |f(t)|<1 \forall{t\in{[0,1]}}\}$ is an open set in $C[0,1]$ with the supremum metric.

Tags: metric-spaces

By definition, I need to show that every point in $A$ is an interior point in $A$. Do I go about this by showing $A'$ is closed? Please help.

Correction in the title: For all $t\in{[0,1]}$.

Comment: You mean $t\in[0,1]$ in the title.

Comment: Assuming $\;A\;$ is closed won't give you a contradiction proof. For that you need to assume $\;A\;$ isn't open (which is **not** the same as being closed)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $[0,1]$ is compact; what does this imply about the maximum / minimum values of $f$?

Given this, convince yourself that

$$\|f - g\| < \epsilon \implies \max_{t \in [0,1]} |g(t)| < \max_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)| + \epsilon$$

Can you finish it from here?

---

Remark: Showing that $A$ is closed doesn't help at all, since open and closed are *not* opposites of each other.

Comment: We haven't talked about compactness but I'm guessing the minimum and maximum values of $f$ are $0$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: @user121087 No information is given about the maximum and minimum values of $f$; for example, $f$ *could* be the constant function $1/2$. The relevance of compactness is the [extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) which implies that $f$ actually attains its maximum in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Show its **complement** is **closed**. Let $f_n$ be a convergent sequence such that $f_n(t_n)\geqslant 1$ for a sequence of points $t_n\in [0,1]$. Let $t_{n_k}$ be a convergent subsequence, guaranteed by Bolzano Weiertrass. I claim that if $t_0=\lim t_{n_k}$, then $f(t_0)\geqslant 1$. Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly, in particular $f_{n_k}\to f$ uniformly, so $1\leqslant f_{n_k}(t_{n_k})\to f(t_0)$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how this way involves the supremum metric though.

Comment: @user121087 It is crucial to prove $f_{n_k}(t_{n_k})\to f(t_0)$. =)

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thanks!